# Possible way to "merge" sentences that are spaced out far away from each other?

Tags: notepad++, merge

[image]

I want to get rid of the space between the sentences, doesn't matter if they conjoin but I'd rather they stay close but under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace 1 or more linebreak with 1 of the same type.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\R)+`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           :  start group 1
  \R        : any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
)+          : end group, may appear 1 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1, ie. a linebreak
```